# How to get value from HTML set using ngModel in Typescript

Tags: angular, angular-material

I understand this is possibly a duplicate question.
I have an input box in which I am setting the value using ngModel.
Now I want to get that value and store it using typescript.
Can someone help me how do I do that.
HTML Code:

```
 <mat-label> City:
    <input class="editcustomer" [(ngModel)]="element.city" />
 </mat-label>
```

Do I use getElementbyId or is there some other way?

Comment: what is a type of the input? it is a text box or what?

Comment: Have a look at this article https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @YashRami Yes it is text box

Comment: In order to access the input value in your component, use `this.element.city`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="element.city" (ngModelChange)="myFunction($event)">
```

**TS**

```
myFunction(event: any): any {
console.log(event); // here you are getting the value
}
```

but i suggest you to implement the template driven form or reactive form
here you can find more information about that 
[Reactive From](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [template driven from](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

You are using a reactive form so this way is better

**TS**

```
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
 <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
</form>
```

**TS**

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.myForm); // here you will get all the values
}
```

Comment: I am using reactive form. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Can I use the same function on multiple ngModel? There are multiple ngModel like country,zip code etc so how do I do for all?

Comment: yeah you can also do that. But if you want to access the data at submit time then this way is not good. In reactive from you can access all the form data in form object.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the current code as you are already binding the element object with the `[(ngModel)]` property so no need to call `ngModelChange()` method. You can use `this.element` anywhere in the TS code to get the object with the latest values.

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fr8n4c)